# How to change graticules to eastings and northings in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, grids-graticules

I've seen them represented as eastings and northings before, but I can't figure out how to change them over in the Element tab.

[image]

Comment: As I understand it graticules are, by definition, gographic coordiates https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/3.1/help/layouts/add-and-modify-graticules.htm. If you want lines with eastings/northings you should be looking at grids. Is your maps coordinate system geographic or projected?

Answer (score 2):

In ArcGIS Pro, when incorporating a grid, opt for a **Measured Grid** [image].

This feature enables the selection of the coordinate system for graticules, displaying the coordinates corresponding to the chosen coordinate system.

[image]